# Expand (unbalanced) rows between two dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with monthly data. A sample is below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2010-02-28', '2010-04-30', '2010-01-31', '2010-03-31'], 'group': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
```

I want to insert the month end dates between the starting date and the ending date for each group. The problem is each group has different starting and ending dates.

Below is what I tried. However, the result has the same starting date and ending date and the new_date-group combination is not unique.

```
df['new_date'] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start='2010-01-31', end='2010-04-30', freq = 'M'), axis=1)
df = df.explode('new_date').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas-dataframe-resample):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

(df.set_index('date')
 .groupby('group', as_index=False)
 .resample('M').asfreq().reset_index()
 .ffill().drop('level_0', axis=1))
```

Output:

```
        date group
0 2010-02-28     A
1 2010-03-31     A
2 2010-04-30     A
3 2010-01-31     B
4 2010-02-28     B
5 2010-03-31     B
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.date_range` in a `groupby_apply`:

```
>>> (df.groupby('group')['date']
       .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x.min(), x.max(), freq='M')))
       .droplevel(1).reset_index())

  group       date
0     A 2010-02-28
1     A 2010-03-31
2     A 2010-04-30
3     B 2010-01-31
4     B 2010-02-28
5     B 2010-03-31
```

Comment: It seems the solution doesn't work if one of groups has consecutive months? Here is an example: df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2009-10-31', '2010-02-28', '2010-04-30', '2010-01-31', '2010-02-28'], 'group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B']})
Using the code above, group A is filled with dates until 2010-02-28 while it should be filled until 2010-04-30

Comment: I updated my answer. I replaced `.iloc[0]` by `.min()` and `.iloc[1]` by `.max()`